# Perl Regex Explanation

Tags: regex, perl

Hey So I am not good with regex right now, trying to learn though, can someone explain this one out for me bit by bit?

```
if ($fileStrings[$stringCount] =~ m/((?:include|require)(?:_once)?\s*\(.*?\$.*?\);)/gi)
```

Thanks

Comment: see [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm) - explanation of a regular expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
m/((?:include|require)(?:_once)?\s*(.?\$.?);)/gi
```

`m` match for

`/` pattern delimiter

`(?:include|require)` match but not capture 'include' or 'require'

`(?:_once)?` optionally match for but not capture '_once'

`\s*` 0 or more spaces or tabs, other "whitespace" characters

`(.?\$.?)` match and capture 0 or 1 of any character, followed by literal $ character, 
followed by 0 or 1 of any character

`;` match for semicolon

`(...)` outer parenthesis - capture whole thing

`/` pattern delimiter

`gi` global, case-insensitive search

Comment: why look for 0 or more spaces or tabs?

Comment: Actually `\s` matches more than just spaces, and tabs. It matches white-space characters such as *newline*, *carriage-return* *vertical-tab*, as-well as all the Unicode white-space characters. See [perldoc perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Whitespace) for more information.

Comment: @noledgeispower: well don't ask me, I didn't write it, I just explained it

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: I actually know very little perl, I was going off of pcre regex for php. From there, \s will match those additional things (notably the newline chars) with some modifiers, I assumed it was same for perl, since it's pcre and all.. is it really default to match those other things? edit: I guesso, according to your link

Comment: Actually, recent versions of Perl have several additional enhancements over what you will find in PCRE. Including speed improvements, and additional syntax. [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: @Brad: Recent versions of PCRE are pretty good.  The main difference is that Perl has full Unicode support, and the `(?{code})` and `(??{code})` blocks work. Also, you can only recurse into groups that have completed already in PCRE, but in Perl, they don’t have to have finished yet. I haven’t checked for whether it only supports the equivalent of `%+` or whether it also covers `%-`.

Comment: @Brad: `\s` does not match `\x0B`, which is a Unicode whitespace character matched by `\v`. And if you are in non-Unicode byte mode, it will miss  `\xA0` and `\x85`. It turns out that `[\h\v]` is safer.

Comment: @tchrist I was wondering if it was actually **all** ws chars. I should have worded it as *including Unicode white-space characters*

Comment: @brad: In Unicode mode, `\s` is like `\p{White_Space}` minus `\x0B`. In byte/locale mode, it is up to the vendor stuff at best, and probably only works for ASCII otherwise. I strongly encourage everyone to eschew the non-Unicode modes.

Answer (score 0):

I usually find it easy to write a test program to check my thoughts. Maybe this will help you understand what the regex is doing:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw(say);

for my $line (
    'include_once  F$G;',
    'require_once  F$G;',
    'INCLUDE  F$G;',
    'include_once      AF$G;',
    'include_once  F$G;',
) {
    if ($line =~ m/((?:include|require)(?:_once)?\s*(.?\$.?);)/gi) {
        say qq(Line = "$line");
        say qq(\$1 = "$1");
        say qq(\$2 = "$2"\n);
    }
    else {
        say qq(Line = "$line");
        say "No match!\n";
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Line = "include_once  F$G;"
$1 = "include_once  F$G;"
$2 = "F$G"

Line = "require_once  F$G;"
$1 = "require_once  F$G;"
$2 = "F$G"

Line = "INCLUDE  F$G;"
$1 = "INCLUDE  F$G;"
$2 = "F$G"

Line = "include_once      AF$G;"
No match!

Line = "include_once  F$G;"
$1 = "include_once  F$G;"
$2 = "F$G"
```

The parentheses are used to capture parts of the regular expression is the variables `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. The `?:` doesn't allow the parentheses to capture that part (thus, you have `$2` instead of `$4` with the value). However, the outer parentheses capture the entire line despite the `?:`.

It looks like the `g` parameter at the end allows for multiple lines to be captured. However, that didn't work in my tests.